# TypeORM One-To-One relation foreign key not working with TypeGraphQL

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I would like to migrate some endpoints for a REST API developed in NodeJs to GraphQL endpoints.
`TypeOrm` has been used for the database communication, so I figured out that there is a library `type-graphql`, which can ease the migration phase. However, when it comes down to properties which are referred as foreign keys e.g.:

```
@OneToOne(() => SomeModel)
@JoinColumn()
someModel!: SomeModel;
```

the decorator `@Field` does not help, as it considers the property `someModel` as null. Thought of changing the property to a column, but that would mess up the database table, since it should not be included as a column.

Has anybody encountered a similar situation and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by wrapping the property type with a promise

```
@Field(() => SomeModel)
@OneToOne(() => SomeModel)
@JoinColumn()
someModel!: Promise<SomeModel>;
```

I got the hint in the documentation of [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/), underneath the section about `Interoperable`